# Can I use TinyMCE formats config to set a different class for different elements given alignment?

Tags: css, tinymce, css-selectors

For example, I was using

```
formats : {
    alignleft : {selector : 'img', classes : 'float-left'},
    alignright : {selector : 'img', classes : 'float-right'},
    }
```

To apply a float class to left/right aligned img elements rather than inline styles. I know I can technically just add ',p' to the selectors to also give them the "float-left/right" classes and then tweak the class selector in the CSS for p elements but I'd rather give them a different class of "text-right/left".

I tried appending `alignleft : {selector : 'p', classes : 'text-left'}` to the formats config array but it just overrode the img float class config.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Answer (score 1):

try this tinymce config

```
formats: {
    alignleft: [
        {selector : 'div.nb-image,img', classes: 'float-left'},
        {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table', styles: {'text-align': 'left'}}
    ],
    aligncenter: [
        {selector : 'div.nb-image,img', classes: 'float-center'},
        {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table', styles: {'text-align': 'center'}}
    ],
    alignright: [
        {selector : 'div.nb-image,img', classes: 'float-right'},
        {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table', styles: {'text-align': 'right'}}
    ],
    alignfull: [
        {selector : 'div.nb-image,img', classes: 'float-full'},
        {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table', styles: {'text-align': 'justify'}}
    ]
}
```